# any way to change DM name? discord js 12

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a DM with friends and we have a [war](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpwpt.png) going on right now. Can i change DM name using bot on discord js 12?

Comment: What do you mean with "DM"? Looks like you are trying to rename a channel name.

Comment: Bots cannot join group dms, because you cannot friend them. And if you used a selfbot your account would be banned for accessing the dm channel endpoint

Answer (score -1):

This would involve selfbotting, which is not supported by the discord.js library as [it is against Discord TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).